# How to write a generic alert message using win32?

Tags: c++, winapi

I just want to expand this following method into something more generic, which should accept any kind of argument and display it using MessageBox():

```
void alert(char *item)
{
  MessageBox(NULL, item,  "Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
template<typename T>
void alert(T item)
{
//this accepts all types that supports operator << 
  std::ostringstream os;
  os << item;
  MessageBoxA(NULL, os.str().c_str(),  "Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

//now you need specialization for wide char
void alert(const wchar_t* item)
{

  MessageBoxW(NULL, item,  "Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

Comment: You're missing the declaration of `os` in the wide char case. Otherwise good answer. +1

Comment: Second function isn't `specialization`. It is overloading. And you missed `;` in `os << item`.

Answer (score 2):

You could write something like the following:

```
template<typename T>
void alert(T item)
{
  MessageBox(NULL, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(item).c_str(),  "Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

You should specialize `boost::lexical_cast` for any argument type you want since it supports limited range of types.

---

Another way is to use `boost::format`:

```
// helper class
class msg_helper_t {
public:
    msg_helper_t(const char* msg ) : fmt(msg) {}
    ~msg_helper_t() { 
        MessageBox(NULL, str( fmt ).c_str(),  "Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION); 
    }

    template <typename T>
    msg_helper_t& operator %(const T& value) {
        try {
            fmt % value;
        } catch ( std::exception e ) {
            // some exceptional actions
        }
        return *this;
    }
    template <>
    msg_helper_t& operator %(const CString& value) {
        try {
            fmt % value.GetString();
        } catch ( std::exception e ) {
            // some exceptional actions
        }
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    boost::format   fmt;
};

// our message function
msg_helper_t MyMsgBox(const char* msg) { return msg_helper_t( msg ); }
```

Later it could be used in the following way:

```
   MyMsgBox( "Hello with %d arguments: %s" ) % 2 % "some text";
   MyMsgBox( "%d" ) % 123456;
   MyMsgBox( "%f" ) % 10.5f;
```

Comment: can we do it without using boost library ?

Comment: `boost::lexcial_cast<T>` doesn't need specializing; implement an appropriate `operator<<(ostream&, T)` instead.

Comment: @UK: boost::lexical_cast<> is a simple template, you can nick the implementation without pulling all of Boost in.

Comment: UK, you could make the same without boost (by using streams). But `boost` makes life easier.

Comment: All lexical_cast does is basically create a std::stringstream, feed the variable to it, and extract the result using operator >>. So yes, you could easily do it without the boost library.

Answer (score -1):

Since C++ is statically typed, you'll probably need to do one of two things:

1. Use a class hierarchy and have alert take a pointer/reference to a base class which contains some kind of virtual "`toString()`" function (the Java/.NET approach).  The downside here is that `alert()` now only works for types in that class hierarchy.
2. Overload the alert function for types that can't be directly converted to a string, with the downside that you have to duplicate code.

Also, you should make sure to use `MessageBoxA` if you're using ANSI strings, otherwise you should consider using TCHAR and MessageBox or wchar_t and MessageBoxW.